# FindMinimum yields result, but still issues MachinePrecision digits error

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I'm writing a bit of code for a project. I am attempting to find the minimum x-value for a function, which I did get, but Mathematica still threw an error at me. My code is as following:

```
F[t_] := ((1/8)*(((0.1*t) - 3)^5)) - 0.5*(((0.1*t) - 3)^3)
G[t_] := ((0.1*t) - 3)^2
S[t_] := Sqrt[((F'[t])^2) + ((G'[t])^2)]
FindMinimum[S[t], {t, 30}]
```

The result yielded this output:

> FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
>       {0., {t -> 30.}}

I did attempt to work with certain syntax portions, but I am a bit lost as of now. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `S[30]` is `0.` and the minimum cannot be lower than that, so FindMinimum is hardly needed here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
F[t_] = ((1/8)*(((0.1*t) - 3)^5)) - 0.5*(((0.1*t) - 3)^3) // 
   Rationalize;

G[t_] = ((0.1*t) - 3)^2 // Rationalize;

S[t_] = Sqrt[((F'[t])^2) + ((G'[t])^2)] // Simplify;

Minimize[S[t], t]

(* {0, {t -> 30}} *)

NMinimize[S[t], t, WorkingPrecision -> 25] // N

(* {7.77079*10^-14, {t -> 30.}} *)
```

As stated in the documentation "FindMinimum[f, {x, x0, x1}] searches for a local minimum in f using x0 and x1 as the first two values of x, avoiding the use of derivatives."

```
FindMinimum[S[t], {t, 29, 31}]

(* {0., {t -> 30.}} *)
```

The `Plot` shows why the derivative is a problem at `t == 30`

```
Plot[S[t], {t, 0, 60}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put a left and right bound on FindMinimum. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

NMinimize solves your problem directly(global minimum)

```
NMinimize[S[t], {t, 30}]
(*{4.47035*10^-9, {t -> 30.}}*)
```